# Managing UIView animation while moving between different VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

As a beginner I'm struggling on some basic stuff.

So, i have an animation on a view in my main `UIViewController`, but when I'm moving to a different `UIViewController` and then come back to the main one the animation stops.

Well, my animation is in `viewDidLoad()`, already tried to call it from `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()`, but probably that's not the solution.
Unfortunately i can't figure out where call back the animation, does anyone ever been through this small problem?

If can help, that's the code I'm using:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay:0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.viewAnima.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What's the problem in viewWillAppear() ?

Comment: viewWillAppear() is called but, after changing VC the view that should be animate(scaled) is stuck from it previous animation. I don't know if you get me, is a bit tricky to explain.

Comment: ViewWillAppear is fine. Right before your code above add this line. self.viewAnima.transform = .identity .

Comment: Thanks @agibson007 that works for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidAppear is not the correct place to fire the animation. instead

Eg. Have a delegate. 
Implement delegate in the first viewcontroller. when dismissing the second viewController, call the delegate. and put the animation block inside it and trig the animation with 0.2 sec delay. that gives feel like dismissing view and starting animation.

// Put this code inside the delegate function.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(.now()+0.2) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
            // Do you animation here
           })
        }
```